# Fade-in effect with a transparent panel C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, and on that form there is a menu bar (with a 'Run' button), 4 buttons and a pictureBox (just for example). On top of those controls, there is a custom panel which supports opacity.

[image: Original form before clicking 'Run']

What I want to achieve is the custom panel will fade in when I click on 'Run', as shown in the figure below,

[image: Form after click 'Run']

However, the panel will not show the fading effect, but rather flicker or just appear. The fade-in apparently got worse if I drop some controls onto the panel. I just need to know why it won't render properly, or rather is there a better way to do this?

*The opacity of the panel is between 0 - 100.

```
 public Form1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     transparentPanel1.Opacity = 0;
     transparentPanel1.Hide()        
 }

 private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     transparentPanel1.Show();
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i += 10)
     {
         transparentPanel1.Opacity = i;
         transparentPanel1.Refresh();
         this.Refresh();
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Don't use the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();` method, it pauses the whole application, use something like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: I see...i modified the routine using a timer, the fading effect is working, but there is some flickering (minor but noticeable). Is this a limitation for winForms?

Comment: Adding to **shad0wk**'s fine comment, you should drag the `Timer` from the **Toolbox** onto your form.  If you attempt to add `Timer` to your form programatically you might end up getting a different .NET timer (of which there are **4**) that isn't WinForms compatible (such as `System.Threading.TImer`)

Comment: The flicker is cause by winforms itself. Winforms doesn't really support transparency. The main problem is this: `cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20  // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`. *(The code is in the override of CreateParams)*.

Comment: Yeah, I use that to give transparency to my panel. Hence, as suggested by many, WPF is more suitable for this kind of feature?

Comment: WPF is pretty good, but there's one thing, try setting DoubleBuffered to true?

Comment: I tested that, by enabling DoubleBuffered property on the custom panel, but the opacity won't work anymore, it just display solid color. Guess to achieve the effect I want, I will just try it on WPF.